# excel vba does not find outlook 2010 appointment using restrict filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, outlook

I am having a problem with a calendar in Outlook 2010 that is driving me nuts. I am fairly new to both Outlook and VBA, so I might be overlooking something fairly obvious. However, after much research and testing I have not found a solution.

Using Excel VBA I have added birthdays to an Outlook 2010 calendar as all day appointments (start time 12:00 AM on starting day and end 12:00 AM on following day). When I subsequently try to find the appointment using the following filter, the program returns nothing for that date (in the example, 14.10.2018 should contain 1 appointment):

```
Dim dAppDate as Date
dAppDate = "14.10.2018"
sFilter = "[Start] = '" & Format$(dAppDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "'"
Set onamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = onamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = oFolder.Items
Set oFilterAppointments = oItems.Restrict(sFilter)
```

If, however, I just change the filter slightly as follows:

```
sFilter "[Start] >= '" & Format$(dAppDate, "dd.mm.yyyy") & "'"
```

I get all appointments AFTER 14.10.2018, but not the one for that date. Any ideas? This is driving me bats..I have also tried including the start time (12:00 AM) in the filter, but that brought no joy either. Any ideas will be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues:

- The date string must be in an unambiguous format, so either spell out the month, or use something like "yyyy/mm/dd"
- At least here in the US, I was not able to get the `=` operator to work when searching for dates, so I tried a combined filter and that worked:

---

```
sFilter = "[Start] > '" & Format(dAppDate - 1, "yyyy/mm/dd") & "'" & " AND [End] < '" & Format(dAppDate + 1, "m/d/yyyy") & "'"
```

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks very much for your input. I'm somehow relieved that I am not the only one who can't make the '=' operator work in this situation, but it is annoying to have to resort to a kludge. I wonder if there is an official explanation for this behaviour somewhere.

Comment: @BobWinMunich Dates behave unexpectedly in Excel VBA. I've not seen any documentation for this behavior; and none of the examples I have come across in Google searches have used the `=` operator with dates, although it seems to work OK with text.

Comment: @BobWinMunich It isn't any less of a kludge, and might take longer to run on a large data base, but you could also loop through all the appointment items, and `Collect` (in a `Collection` or `Dictionary` object, those where `Start = dAppdate`

Comment: Have you checked this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/search-the-calendar-for-appointments-within-a-date-range-that-contain-a-specific

Comment: @SimonLi Yes, but we are looking for an explanation of why the equals `=` operator, by itself, doesn't work.  That example still uses a date range.